# facebook c# sdk: deleting a request-id

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the latest facebook c# sdk (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/). After i have sent an apprequest, i want to delete the request id.

This is how i do it at the moment:

```
var app = new FacebookClient(appid, appsecret);
app.Delete(requestID);
```

But i am not sure if its get deleted or not. If i try to see if it still exist using the graph api i get:

```
{
"error": {
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "message": "Unsupported get request."
   }
}
```

But the user still has the request in his notification area. So my question is> Is the request deleted, or did i miss something? Thanks

Comment: Did you try refreshing the page?

Comment: what is the return message when you try to delete the post?
i have the exact same code and it works for my app.
and which url do you use to get the request ?

Answer (score 2):

```
        var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{0}?access_token={1}";
        fb.Delete((String.Format(url, fullRequestId, fb.AccessToken)));
```

First parameter is requestId and user id like -> fullRequestId = requestId + "_" + fbUser.id
Second parameter is Accesstoken

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting started on this myself, but I'm guessing that you need to instantiate the FacebookClient with the authorization code from the user, not with your application data.  The way I understand it, the request is sent by the user not your application.  Hence the need to use the users authorization code to get information about the requeset.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's working for me (sorry it's VB.Net):

```
Dim fb As FacebookClient = New FacebookClient(Config.FacebookAppId,Config.FacebookAppSecret)
Dim result = fb.Delete(String.Format("{0}_{1}?access_token={2}", facebookRequestId, facebookUserId, fb.AccessToken))
```